# Is there a way to create and edit an Envelope via web page?

Tags: docusignapi

I need to add DocuSign to my chat app (iOS, Android, Windows) in order to ask to sign documents to all the group members.

Do I need to build my own native UI for the "Envelope creation" process? 
Otherwise is there a DocuSign web page for this purpose?

The only way I found to create an Envelope and avoid custom native UI is using rest call `/envelopes` and call `/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/views/correct` for the document edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed the "sending" part of an envelope in your app just like you can embed the signing. 
You make an API call to get a URL that enables you to let your users make any change, add/remove documents, add/remove recipients, place tags and use all other tagger features.
Is that going to work for you?

Comment: Ok thanks, can you suggest me the exact endpoint to get the URL for the "sending" part?

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-sending has code examples in 6 languages if you're using one of our SDKs

Comment: POST ${base_path}/v2/accounts/${account_id}/envelopes/${envelope_id}/views/sender

Comment: great. Do you mind marking this question as answered?